# Using getIdentifier() to Find ID of Image

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am trying to get id of an image by using following code.

```
 public class MovieActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private Context con;
        String name = "test";
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                con = MovieActivity.this;
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie);
            }

    public void updateScreen(){

            int imageResource = con.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + name , null, con.getPackageName());

        }

    }
```

When I run it, I get exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I thought the problem was `Context` so I added `con` variable which gets context when code runs. I made some researches and tried another methods but I got same exception every time. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: When I use the same code line in MainActivity, it works perfectly. But in another class, it fails.

```
public class SomeMovie extends MovieActivity {  }

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          SomeMovie movie = new SomeMovie();
          movie.updateScreen();

      }
 }
```

SomeMovie class is child of `MovieActivity` class. I call the method on that. I debugged the code and noticed that `Context` is null when code gets into `updateScreen()` method. Is it wrong to use inheritance on activity classes?

Comment: You dont need the context.
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + name , null, con.getPackageName());

Comment: @Actiwitty I am getting same error when I remove context

Comment: yet another ... do not use `new Activity()` !!!!!

Comment: Can you remove the `con = MovieActivity.this;` line as well?

Comment: it dosn't matter, he obviously is using this method like `new MovieActivity().updateScreen()`

Comment: @Selvin but I need to use another activity than MainActivity in my project

Comment: @Actiwitty I tried it too but got same exception again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int imageResource = con.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + name , null, con.getPackageName());
```

to

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + name , null, con.getPackageName());
```

You are already in an `Activity`'s context, so use it. (No need to use the `this` keyword to refer to it)

**EDIT:**

You are not defining a layout for the `SomeMovie` Activity, so its `context` is always `null`. 
You have to define the activity's layout in its `onCreate` method :

```
public class SomeMovie extends MovieActivity {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.somemoviexml);
          ...

      }
 }
```

Comment: @berkc post all of your code. There must be something we're missing... Perhaps you're calling the `updateScreen` method in a wrong way.

Comment: This whole Activity instantiation inside another one thing is a bad idea.

Comment: I have 2 layouts, updateScreen() method changes one of the layouts. Code starts at activity_main.xml and when a button clicked it switches to other layout. Before switch process, I wanted to use updateScreen method to update other layout. That's what I was trying to do but I don't get why context is null in another class. Is MainActivity only class with context?

Comment: I got same error. I debugged again and noticed my code never enters onCreate method on MovieActivity class. Shouldn't code get in it when I call it on MainActivity class?

Comment: you left the chat, I really need help. Will you able to help me or should I try other solutions?